# Add new Android project to the forked repo

Tags: android, git, kotlin, gradle, setup-project

I am trying to add a new Android Kotlin project for an assignment to a forked repo which has only an assets folder and a README file, but I am failing to do so.

I tried to create a new module, but I am failing with all the required Gradle files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need it to be forked if it's almost empty? Just creating a new repo seems the simplest solution here.

If you don't want to create a new one:

1. Clone your forked project, then transfer the essential files of your new project to your cloned project, commit, push and you are ready.
2. Force-push your new project into the forked repo. This will destroy git's previous history and you probably won't be able to do a PullRequest to the original project you forked.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've forked the assignment repo where I have some pictures I need to use for my project in the Assets folder as well as the README file with the tasks, and I need to create a pull request for this repo once I am finished. I have no problem with forking the repo but since the project file is in the forked repo, I cannot make a new Android project inside it with all the Gradle files and a proper App structure. I am wondering if there is anything I could do inside the Android studio to recreate the normal project structure, but I cannot find anything useful for that matter

Comment: Did you try the (1) I suggested? it will solve your problem... You just need to be careful not to overwrite any *.git files when copy/pasting your new project's files. If you're unsure about something, please tell me to clarify even further.

Comment: thanks for your help!! I think it was something to do with the git files indeed, I tried your (1) solution again, and it worked fine! thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Is it compulsory for the new project to be linked to the forked repo? I would advise you create a new project entirely then add the files from the forked repo manually through file explorer.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for your help. Could you please get a look at my comment on rtsketo answer above?

Answer (score 0):

Just `git clone` that fork (which is technically a server-side clone)... then you have github.com added as `origin/master`. There you can either push directly, or create a new branch, where to `git push` to.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've forked the assignment repo where I have some pictures I need to use for my project in the Assets folder as well as the README file with the tasks, and I need to create a pull request for this repo once I am finished. I have no problem with forking the repo but since the project file is in the forked repo, I cannot make a new Android project inside it with all the Gradle files and a proper App structure. I am wondering if there is anything I could do inside the Android studio to recreate the normal project structure, but I cannot find anything useful for that matter